# extract list of functions in header file

Tags: c++, parsing, header-files

I am looking for a way to extract all functions found in a C++ header file including comments for that respective function which sit on top of the function definition.

The idea is to produce a list of all functions in the file in order to get it into a CSV or Excel file. I would like to have on each line:

Header file name;Function name only;Complete function signature;Comments in code for that function

Example (from file someHeader.h):

```
// This is the multi-line
// comment for the DoSomething function.
void            DoSomething (int CleverParameter);
```

turned into

```
someHeader.h;DoSomething;void DoSomething (int CleverParameter);This is the multi-line comment for the DoSomething function.
```

I don't need clever parsing and type/dependency resolution or such things. I have VisualStudio 2010 and 2012 at my hands. Also not afraid of Linux or Windows command-line tools. If whitespace gets cleaned up in the process, that would be great.

Comment: If you don't need an accurate answer, then a regex will do about well as anything (e.g.,  badly).  Otherwise you are going to discover that to extract such function definitions you need a full preprocessor to resolve macros and conditionals (maybe you can run the header through the preprocessor first to resolve this).  Even with that, C++'s syntax is arcane enough (and MS's variant is worse because of its 30 year history) so whatever non-clever parsing solution you choose will get false negatives and false positives.

Comment: You say you're not afraid of Linux.  I don't know how you'll be throwing your code between Windows and Linux but if you can get it between the two fairly easy and don't really care take a look at 'lex'.  I'm positive you can find predefined scanners for C/C++.

Comment: Look at `ctags` - it will do most of the parsing job for you (though without comments).

Comment: ctags looks nice and gets me there halfway. I don't get comments in the tag file (which is okay). But I also don't get tags for function definitions which use types defined in other files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a decent C++ parser won't be an easy task.

A possible solution would be to use a documentation generator such as [doxygen's](http://www.doxygen.nl/), it doesn't include a complete C++ parser but it should be sufficient for your purpose:

- Use doxygen to generates an XML output containing all function definitions and comments
- Use an XSLT stylesheet or an XML parser to generates your CSV file

It's not the perfect solution, but it would definitely be more robust than a regex approach and won't require a lot of code to get it working.

Comment: "Won't be easy" is the understatement of the year.  We've been working continuously on ours for about 5 years.    Doxygen is workable, but not accurate, simply because it isn't a real C++ parser.  It is probably better than a regex solution.

Comment: The doxygen approach is pretty close. Since I don't have the time right now to learn enough about XML postprocessing, I'll just bluntly copy things from the HTML output. Thanks very much!