# Parsing text/*.h file to identify and extract function headers

Tags: c++

Using standard c++, I want to read the contents of a header(.h) file into memory then parse the file data to identify and extract the function headers.

One way to detect a function is via its return type.

Given the function header will be embedded in a string, how best to test that a string fragment is indeed a valid c++ type?

Of course we could just store a list of standard return types, but this wouldn't work for user defined types.

If this is not possible then what alternative solution to identify function header in a text/.h file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract list of functions in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125936/extract-list-of-functions-in-header-file)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but would prefer to resolve this via home grown standard c++.

Comment: Then you'll need to implement sort of parser and preprocessor which seems quite complex

Comment: What you are doing is trying to write a C++ pre-processor - I'd have a look at clang AST matchers and not waste your time writing something that is very complex if done correctly